# Не отображается RecyclerView во fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пишу программу интернет магазин, использую bottom navigation view и fragment.
Мне нужно было в одном из фрагментов добавить список товаров, хотел сделать это через RecyclerView, но вылезает ошибка в двух местах с "this" - строки 33 и 36

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Дополнение:
Я видимо опять что-то не то делаю, он подчёркивает его желтым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Дополнение-2.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо this использовать activity.

Comment: Теперь подчёркивается только в 36 строке, в 33 строке ошибка исчезла, прикрепил фото

Comment: Предлагаю из конструктора адаптера убрать context и внутри его брать из parent.context

Comment: Все ошибки ушли, спасибо.

Comment: Но)
Во фрагменте ничего не отображается, с чем это может быть связано

Comment: Возможно, не вызвали notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Да, подскажите где нужно его вызывать?)

Comment: В конце метода setCategoryRecycler вызовите его для адаптера.

Comment: Я видимо опять что-то не то делаю, он подчёркивается желтым цветом. Добавил фото

Comment: categoryRecycler?.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Также подчеркивает желтым

Comment: Желтое - это не ошибка, а предупреждение. По-прежнему, нет данных в RecyclerView?

Comment: нет не отображается

Comment: К сожалению, тогда не смогу подсказать. Проверяйте разметку, используйте отладчик.

Comment: при отладке вылезает вот такая ошибка: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Может быть в этом проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен!
В моем случае проблема была в том, что я вызывал создание списка в методе onCreate, а нужно было в методе onStart.
После того как я поместил всё в onStart всё заработало.

Comment: Правильнее в `onViewCreated`

Comment: Здравствуйте, я поместил код туда, но всё равно не отображается.
До того момента как я добавил ещё один recyclerview в свой фрагмент. список отображался, когда он был в методе onStart.
После этого теперь не отображается ни тот ни этот.

Comment: При необходимости я выложил ещё раз вопрос, его можно посмотреть здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1405341/Не-отображается-recyclerview-в-fragment